# Commands not running in gradle gui

Tags: gradle, gradlew

when ever i am trying to use gradle gui with the following command:

`./gradlew --gui`

It shows an errorlike this [image]

- Gradle is not installed, as i am using gradle wrapper
- Gradle version in wrapper is 2.10
- oracle java 8

Comment: please run `gradle tasks --info --stacktrace` from the commandline and post the complete error stack.

Comment: @RaGe thank you... you show me a way...:)

Comment: Just for whom looking same error from a modern gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/995 - GUI WAS REMOVED at gradle 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had seen the error on console...

```
Starting external process
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/manisha/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-bin/baigpnfu14tdk6ztbfwcl8275/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle''
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/home/manisha/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-bin/baigpnfu14tdk6ztbfwcl8275/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle'
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
... 5 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/manisha/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-bin/baigpnfu14tdk6ztbfwcl8275/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle" (in directory "/media/manisha/manu/twc/OMEGA"): error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
... 7 more

 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 8 more
```

And i get to know that the issue is in giving permission....

thus, i give execution permission to the file `gradle` under the path `/home/manisha/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-bin/baigpnfu14tdk6ztbfwcl8275/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle` using `sudo chmod 705 gradle` and again run `./gradle --gui` 
And it run SUCCESSFULLY....:)